# Configure OpenSSH SFTP Server to authentificate users against MySQL Database

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, sftp, file-sharing

Im looking for a way to authenticate the users of our OpenSSH SFTP Server against a MySQL Database. This would be nice because I want to add users through a webinterface which will write in the MySQL Database. The reason for this is that I find it kind of a unpleasant solution to add a system user for every client that wants to download data. Also many of these users are going to download files from the same directories so it's absolutely useless to chroot everyone in his own home directory because they should be chrooted in costum directories.

I know I can do this with proftpd and SSL but if I can avoid using FTP I would do so.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/1080616/openssh-with-virtual-users-and-chroot and maybe a duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/319116/virtual-sftp-users-with-openssh

Comment: If you're offering downloads, why not set up a webserver instead?